# Positioning Two Adjacent Textboxes

Tags: html

I have a web page, and I am trying to set up a login section:  I am trying to have two form input boxes next to each other (for email and login information), however, I am also using CSS to customize the boxes.  When I use the code I currently have, the boxes appear in different rows, as opposed to the same row.

Here is the relevant code:

index.html:

```
<div class="loginwrap">
    <div class="logincontent_wrap">
    <div class="logincontent">
    <div class="loginaction">
    <form action="/" method="post" class="invite_form" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="logininput_row">
            <input type="text" class="logininput" value="" name="loginemail" id="loginemail"/>
            <span class="logininput_overlay">Account email</span>
        </div>
        <div class="logininput_row">
            <input type="password" class="logininput" value="" name="loginpassword" id="loginpassword"/>
            <span class="logininput_overlay">Password</span>
        </div>

    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS file:

```
    .loginwrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 900px;
}
.logincontent_wrap {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    /*box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);*/
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}
.logincontent {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px;
}

.logincontent .loginaction {
    float: right;
    width: 400px;
}
.logincontent .loginaction_text {
    color: #555555;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.logincontent .logininput_row {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    margin: 4px 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 140px;
}
.logincontent .loginbutton_row {
    margin: 8px 0;
}
.logincontent .logininput, .logincontent .logininput_overlay {
    color: #777777;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.logincontent .logininput.error {
    -moz-transition: border 0.2s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.2s linear 0s;
    border: 1px solid #EE5F5B;
}
.logincontent .logininput_overlay {
    left: 11px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 0;
}
.logincontent .logininput_overlay.focus {
    color: #CCCCCC;
}
.logincontent .logininput {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    line-height: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 9px 9px 8px;
    position: relative;
    width: 140px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

I know that the div command will make another row, but I don't know the other command to include the class information from the CSS file and have the boxes appear next to each other.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Which elements do you want next to each other? Could you show a picture, or even an ASCII-art sketch?

Comment: Add `float: left;` to the `logininput_row` statement. And I'm not sure you have enough `DIV` elements in there... `;)`

Comment: @DavidThomas - I imagine the OP wants the username and password fields to be next to each other. Asking for ASCII art though is original. `:D`

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mNmgk/

Comment: @JaredFarrish: that code is *awful*; I...suppose your assumption's obvious (without intending that as an insult) but, I couldn't see what was there, nested in all the other `div`s and `span`s... @.@

Comment: @DavidThomas - Oh, it's awful. Especially looking at the fiddle I posted, there are... Problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`div` is a block element thats mean it will have own line.

use in css

```
logininput_row{display: inline}
```

or write both inputs into one div, or use mentioned floating

Comment: This worked, thank you.  I didn't want to "float left" as everyone suggested, because I wanted both boxes on the right side of the wrap.  This is what I was looking for.

Comment: After using this, now my text overlay isn't centered correctly in my text boxes.  Is there a way to solve this (I have this set up with other text boxes, where they are in separate rows, and the text overlay is aligned fine).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the width, but `float: left` should work...

```
.logininput_row {
  float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Mike S. says you can change the display from block to inline. Another way would be to change the positioning by floating the element.

```
.logincontent .logininput_row {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    margin: 4px 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 180px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: `position: relative` is already in that statement in the OPs question...?

Comment: You're right, it was already there, but I added the float:left

Answer (score 0):

This positions the elements next to each other. Note, however, I removed your `position: relative` and `position: absolute` styles, as they are causing issues and probably not necessary. If you want to have `Account Email` and `Password` to show as field hints, there are better ways than what you're doing. For instance, [HTML5's `placeholder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/input#attr-placeholder) is a decent alternative:

http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html

```
.loginwrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 900px;
}
.logincontent_wrap {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    /*box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);*/
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}
.logincontent {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px;
}

.logincontent .loginaction {
    float: right;
    width: 400px;
}
.logincontent .loginaction_text {
    color: #555555;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.logincontent .logininput_row {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    margin: 4px 0;
    width: 140px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    float: left;
}
.logincontent .logininput, .logincontent .logininput_overlay {
    color: #777777;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.logincontent .logininput.error {
    -moz-transition: border 0.2s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.2s linear 0s;
    border: 1px solid #EE5F5B;
}
.logincontent .logininput_overlay {
    /*left: 11px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 0;*/
}
.logincontent .logininput_overlay.focus {
    color: #CCCCCC;
}
.logincontent .logininput {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    line-height: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 9px 9px 8px;
    width: 140px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mNmgk/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
.logininput_row
{
   display:inline-block
   margin:0 5px;
   padding:5px;
}
.logininput_row input
{
   vertical-align:middle;
}
```